# "Illegal Break" when 'Outputting Multiples of a Number, Input 0 or Non # to exit'

Tags: c++, loops, break

Beginner programmer. My assignment is to output multiples of a positive unsigned number, and use a 0 or non # to quit the program. Example run of the program:
12

1   2   3   4   6   12

1

1

100

1   2   4   5   10   20   25   50   100

0

Goodbye!

My code so far seems to work well. However, instead of the "die" command i'm using I want to use a "break". The problem is when I go to write a break instead of a die, I run into an error ("illegal break"). How can I rewrite this code to properly use a "break" followed by a cout <<"Goodbye!" ?

```
 int main(){
unsigned i, n;
cout <<"Positive #: ";
if ( !(cin >>n ) || n == 0 ) die ( "Goodbye!" );
for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
    if ( n%i == 0  )
        cout <<i <<" "; 
        }
cout <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some kind of outer loop that is causing the "Positive #: " line to be continuously output, so that the user can give you multiple entries.
With your current setup, the user should only be able to enter one number, after which point your program should terminate (which is not the desired behaviour).

```
int main(){
unsigned i, n;
while(true)
{
    cout <<"Positive #: ";
    if ( !(cin >>n ) || n == 0 ) break;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
        if ( n%i == 0  )
            cout <<i <<" "; 
         }
}
cout << "Goodbye!";
cout <<endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you could refactor the code to print the query at the end of the loop (and once before the loop begins), and move the conditional in the 'if' to the 'while', in which case you would not even need to use a break statement.

Answer (score 0):

`break` only works inside loops - it breaks outside the loop. You want to *return* from your main function, so use `return`.

Of course, `return` doesn't print anything, so you'd better do:

```
if( ... exit condition... )
{
   cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried this but received an error.

    unsigned i, n;
    cout <<"Positive #: ";
 if ( !(cin >>n ) || n == 0 ){
  cout <<"Goodbye!";
  return 0;
 }
 for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
  if ( n%i == 0  )
   cout <<i <<" "; 
   }